# Which component to use to implement a menu?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I want to display a menu like:

```
Obi Wan Kenobi
  My friends
  Options

My lightsabers
  Blue lightsaber
  Green lightsaber 
  Add a lightsaber
```

As you can see, the `My lightsabers` menu is a list of items, but the link to add a new lightsaber is independent.

I believe I should use a `CollectionView` to render the lightsabers list, but how to render the "add" link?

Do you have any example of such menus?

The question can be generalized in: How to customize bits of HTML rendered by Marionette without breaking thing it does?

Comment: Could you add the `html view` and the `model JSON` to your question

Comment: I don't have any code since i'm totally open. For now i use plain old Backbone view with a render (https://gist.github.com/2634577).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a CompositeView for this, because of the need for the add link.

You would set up a template that contains a placeholder for the actual list, and then has the add link and all the necessary other bits as well. Then modify the `appendHtml` method of the composite view to place the actual items in the correct spot.

For example, here's a template that would get you down the path:

```
<script id="light-saber-menu-template" type="text/html">
  <h4>My Lightsabers</h4>
  <ul id="light-sabers">
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Add A Lightsaber</a></li>
  <ul>
</script>

<script id="light-saber-menu-item-view" type="text/html">
  <%= name %>
</script>
```

In this example, I would use the `divider` ul as the location to put the items, inserting them before the divider:

```
MenuItem = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#light-saber-menu-item-template",
  tagName: "li"
});

MenuView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  template: "#light-saber-menu-template",

  itemView: MenuItem,

  appendHtml: function(cv, iv){
    var $divider = cv.$(".divider");
    $divider.before(iv.el);
  }
});

myLightSabers = new LightSaberCollection(... data ...);

menu = new MenuView({
  collection: myLightSabers
});

menu.render();
```

This should produce a `<ul>` with the items you expect:

```
<div>
  <h4>My Lightsabers</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>Blue</li>
    <li>Green</li>
    <li>Red</li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Add A Lightsaber</a></li>
  </ul>
<div>
```

For more examples on using a CompositeView, see this blog post: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/

Comment: Thanks Derick, it works very well. I was intimidated by composite views but it seems to be the way to go to add bits of HTML to a rendering.